# I/O issue with PowerCenter Informatica in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, io, query-optimization, informatica-powercenter

I have two tables in Oracle and I have to synchronize values (`Field` column) between the tables. I'm using Informatica PowerCenter for this synchronization operation. The source qualifier query causes high I/O usage and I need to solve it.

---

## Table1

Table1 has about 20M data. `Field` in Table1 is the actual field. `Timestamp` field holds create & update date and it has daily partition.

| Id | Field | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2017-05-12 03:13:40 |
| 2 | B | 2002-11-01 07:30:46 |
| 3 | C | 2008-03-03 03:26:29 |

---

## Table2

Table2 has about 500M data. `Field` in Table2 should be as sync as possible to Field in Table1. `Timestamp` field holds create & update date and it has daily partition. Table2 is also target in the mapping.

| Id | Table1_Id | Field | Timestamp | *Action* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | A | 2005-09-30 03:20:41 | *Nothing* |
| 101 | 1 | **B** | 2015-06-29 09:41:44 | *Update Field as A* |
| 102 | 1 | **C** | 2016-01-10 23:35:49 | *Update Field as A* |
| 103 | 2 | **A** | 2019-05-08 07:42:46 | *Update Field as B* |
| 104 | 2 | B | 2003-06-02 11:23:57 | *Nothing* |
| 105 | 2 | **C** | 2021-09-21 12:04:24 | *Update Field as B* |
| 106 | 3 | **A** | 2022-01-23 01:17:18 | *Update Field as C* |
| 107 | 3 | **B** | 2008-04-24 15:17:25 | *Update Field as C* |
| 108 | 3 | C | 2010-01-15 07:20:13 | *Nothing* |

## Mapping Queries

### Source Qualifier Query

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.Id = t2.Table1_Id AND t1.Field <> t2.Field
```

### Update Transformation Query

```
UPDATE Table2
SET
  Field = :tu.Field,
  Timestamp = SYSDATE
WHERE Id = :tu.Id
```

Comment: You haven't actually stated a problem. From your title I'm assuming there's a performance issue. My only suggestion - assuming everything is in the same physical database - would be to use SQL to do this sync directly, and not Informatica. You'll lose a lot of time pulling all of the data out of the database and pushing it back in, row by row.

Comment: My issue is high I/O usage. Everything is in the same database. I assume there is a workaround to use a dynamic lookup cache and not select the same data but I couldn't find a relative example to solve it. https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration/current-version/transformations/lookup-transformation/dynamic-lookup-cache.html

Comment: High I/O in the database, or on the Informatica server?

Comment: High I/O in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach.
SQ - Your SQL is correct and you can use it if you see its working but add a <> clause on partition date key column. You can use this SQL to speed it up as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN  Table1 t3 ON t3.Id = t2.Table1_Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.Id = t2.Table1_Id AND t1.Field = t2.Field AND t1.partition_date= t2.partition_date -- You did not mention partition_date column but i am assuming there is a separate column which is used to partition. 
WHERE t1.id is null -- <> is inefficient.
```

Then in your infa target T2 definition, make sure you mention  partition_date as part of key along with ID.
Then use a update strategy set to `DD_UPDATE`. You can set the session to update as well.
And remove that target override. This actually applies the update query on the whole table and sometime can be inefficient abd I/O intensive.

Informatica is powerful to update data in bunch through update strategy. You can increase commit interval as per your performance.

You shouldn't try to update a 500M table in a single go using SQL. Yes, you can use PLSQL to update in a bunch.